# 500 internal server error image.php

Tags: php, image, hotlinking

I am using a script for printing . but i get inter server error 500 in every images . it is tested script .
is it issue of .htacess , hot link protraction . you can see here 
http://www.saveonshirts.club/design/dist

Answer (score 0):

> is it issue of .htacess

Probably not. A 500 Internal Server Error usually has to do with the script that is being installed. Now, if your web server cannot communicate with PHP it might cause a 500 error, but it's more likely a problem with the script execution.

> hot link protraction

Probably not. It seems like your image generation script is under the same domain as your site.

---

If you can access your error logs and post what those say, it would make it much easier to help further.

Comment: [Sat Sep 19 05:52:38 2015] [error] [client 162.144.46.69] File does not exist: /home/saveonsh/public_html/design/data/undefined, referer: http://www.saveonshirts.club/design/dist/
it is my error log . same script working with free server .

Comment: It seems like something that defines the path to your design data in your script is not working properly. Where you see "undefined" in your error logs is probably a variable that is not being set for some reason. See http://danielnorton.com/2013site/nerd/code/php/isdef.html

Comment: same script and same path is working with other server . http://cube1.0-host.net/dist/#/home

Comment: Well then it's obviously a problem with your current server.